# Moving Emails in Outlook Folders to Subfolder with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have exported all subject of the emails from the main folder to excel spreadsheet in the first module of my project.

For the second module, or code. I would like to move the emails i extracted from the main folder to a sub-folder based on searching the email subject. I detailed the subfolder name, on a separate column of the spreadsheet.

Column 3 - The subject email 
Column 8 - The subfolder name

Each email subject in the main folder is unique, So i used the "Find Method" then move the email to the subfolder. Since the list is dynamic every time i make an extract, i decided to use arrays, so that it can iterate when the list of email changes.

Example, the code has to place email in the main folder with subject "A" to folder "1".

```
Email subject        Folder name 
(Column 3)           (Column 8)
A                     1
B                     1
C                     2
D                     2
E                     1
```

```
Sub MovingEmails_Invoices()

  'Declare your Variables
    Dim i As Object
    Dim items As Outlook.items
    Dim subfolder As Outlook.Folder 'this will be the folder you want to move the Mail to

    'Set Outlook Inbox Reference
    Set OP = New Outlook.Application
    Set NS = OP.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'To loop through subfolder and its folders
    Set rootfol = NS.Folders("SYNTHES-JNJCZ-GBS.DE.AT.CH@ITS.JNJ.com")
    Set Folder = rootfol.Folders("Austria")


'The list for invoice numbers and folders is dynamic
'Each subject being searched is different

Dim Listmails() As Variant
Dim Rowcount As Variant
Dim Mailsubject As Variant
Dim FolderName As Variant
Dim MS As Variant

 'Establish the array based on the mailbox extract
  Sheets("files").Activate
  Listmails = Range("A2").CurrentRegion

 'Ititerate through the array which is dynamic (One-dimensional)
 For Rowcount = LBound(Listmails) To UBound(Listmails)

 '3rd row for email subject
  Mailsubject = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Listmails, Rowcount, 3)
  MS = "[subject] = '" & Mailsubject & "'"

 'Find the email based on the array for email subject
  Set i = items
  Set i = Folder.items.Find(MS)

  If i.Class = olMail Then

 '8th row for folder name
  FolderName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Listmails, Rowcount, 8)
  Set subfolder = rootfol.Folders(FolderName)

  'If email is found then mark it as read
  item.UnRead = False

 'Move it to the subfolder based on the array for folder name
  i.Move subfolder

End If
Next Rowcount

End Sub
```

I had an error to conduct the below code, but i am not sure why

```
If i.Class = olMail Then
```

I am adding an improved code for the iteration part alone. i have error for

`Set items = items.Restrict(MS)`

```
'Ititerate through the array which is dynamic (One-dimensional)
For Rowcount = LBound(Listmails) To UBound(Listmails)

'3rd row for email subject 'used DASL Filter
Mailsubject = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Listmails, Rowcount, 3)
MS = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject LIKE \'%" & Mailsubject & "%\'"

    'Find the email based on the array for email subject
    Set myitems = Folder.items
    Set myrestrictitem = myitems.Restrict(MS)

      For Each i In myrestrictitem
      If TypeOf i Is Mailitem Then

         '8th row for folder name
         FolderName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Listmails, Rowcount, 8)
         Set subfolder = rootfol.Folders(FolderName)

         'If email found then mark it as read
         i.UnRead = False

         'Move it to the subfolder based on the array for folder name
         i.Move subfolder

      Else
      End If
      Next

Next Rowcount

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: its say for the code  `If i.class = olMail Then` that object with variable or with block variable is not set

Comment: Then it sounds like the `Find` in `Set i = Folder.items.Find(MS)` was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just looking at part of your code, but there's at least two big mistakes I spotted:

Why are you setting `i` twice? Also what is `items`?

```
Set i = items
Set i = Folder.items.Find(MS)
```

1: Do you perhaps want to check the `TypeOf i`?

```
If i.Class = olMail Then
```

2: What is `item`?

```
item.UnRead = False
```

---

Remove the line

```
Set i = items
```

Replace the line

```
If i.Class = olMail then
```

with

```
If TypeOf i Is MailItem Then
```

And replace `item` with `i` in the line `item.UnRead = False`

Comment: Hi Nacorid! your suggestion totally worked i didnt get an error for `If i.Class = olMail then` however my loop still didnt work i rewrote my code at the top if you could help with any ideas, i would be really grateful! thank you

Comment: @Santya Are you sure your `restrict` doesn't return an empty collection?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking the subject line as a substring, for example:

```
dim filter as string = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject LIKE \'%"+ wordInSubject +"%\'"
```

Also, you must use the `FindNext` in addition to the `Find` one or just the `Restrict` method:

```
Sub MovingEmails_Invoices()

  'Declare your Variables
    Dim i As Object
    Dim items As Outlook.items
    Dim subfolder As Outlook.Folder 'this will be the folder you want to move the Mail to

    'Set Outlook Inbox Reference
    Set OP = New Outlook.Application
    Set NS = OP.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'To loop through subfolder and its folders
    Set rootfol = NS.Folders("SYNTHES-JNJCZ-GBS.DE.AT.CH@ITS.JNJ.com")
    Set Folder = rootfol.Folders("Austria")


'The list for invoice numbers and folders is dynamic
'Each subject being searched is different

Dim Listmails() As Variant
Dim Rowcount As Variant
Dim Mailsubject As Variant
Dim FolderName As Variant
Dim MS As Variant

 'Establish the array based on the mailbox extract
  Sheets("files").Activate
  Listmails = Range("A2").CurrentRegion

 'Ititerate through the array which is dynamic (One-dimensional)
 For Rowcount = LBound(Listmails) To UBound(Listmails)

 '3rd row for email subject
  Mailsubject = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Listmails, Rowcount, 3)
  MS = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject LIKE \'%"& Mailsubject &"%\'"

 'Find the email based on the array for email subject
  Set items = Folder.Items
  Set items = items.Restrict(MS)
  i = resultItems.GetFirst()
  While Not IsNothing(i)
     If i.Class = olMail Then

       '8th row for folder name
        FolderName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Listmails, Rowcount, 8)
        Set subfolder = rootfol.Folders(FolderName)

       'If email is found then mark it as read
        i.UnRead = False

        'Move it to the subfolder based on the array for folder name
        i.Move subfolder
        i = resultItems.GetNext()
   End While
End If

Next Rowcount

End Sub
```

You can find the sample code and description in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: The line `If i.Class = olMail Then` will throw an error, as `olMail` is not a vb constant. You should use `MailItem` or `43`

Comment: Hi Eugene, this code seems great but there is a error in VBA for `End While` i also replaced `set items = items.Restrict(MS)` with `set i = items.Restrict(MS) ` i assume thats what you meant. i rewrote this code at my question section again and i used Nacorid suggestion to replace `If i.Class = olMail ` with  `If TypeOf i Is MailItem Then ` but still my loop doesnt seem to work still. Thank you so much still!

Comment: The code  `If TypeOf i Is MailItem Then` worked and didnt give me an error